# determining which client sent data using sockets

Tags: java, swing, datainputstream

I have a problem.

In my code i have an array of players, everyone with his "in" and "out" to the server.

From Server to Clients i can communicate well and without any problem and every client shows in his GUI the change sent by Server.

The problem is the communication from Clients to Server. As Server, I want to recieve petitions from every player to do some work. The problem is that i dont know from which index i recieve the petition and I cant check every `players[index].in.readUTF()` cause it blocks the program.

Some help? `in.avaiable()` doesnt work for me.

To show it clearer:

When a player logs into the Server i do this in the Server Side.

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
out = new DataOutputStream(menuPrincipal.socket.getOutputStream());
in = new DataInputStream(menuPrincipal.socket.getInputStream());
players[i] = new player(i,out,in);
```

Then i have a thread in Server side waiting from messages.

**The problem is that i dont know from which index of players array (from which player) will come the message**. I cant check an index of players that is not sending anything to Server cause it will block the program.

So thats how it works:

From Server to Client I just do:

1. `player[i].out.writeUTF(message)` from Server side
2. Client just does `in.readUTF()` and all works fine

From Client to Server I do:

1. `out.writeUTF(message)` from Client
2. But then on the Server side i have to choose one `player[i].in` **to read which i dont know  which player is.**

Comment: Could you post some of the structure you're using? How are the players logging onto your server?

Comment: array of players ? players is string , integer or object , what ? code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you say you've managed to send data from the Server to the Client, and it works fine. The same principle applies when sending data from client to server.

Have a Listening thread, on the server side. Inside the packet, you can include the name, or the IP address, of the user sending the data. IE:

```
Data Recieved by Server: 'message, hello chris, sender, reciever'
```

Your server can then split up the packet into it's meaningful sections using a string tokenizer.

```
Action: 'message'
Message: 'hello chris'
Sender: 'sender'
Reciever: 'reciever'.
```

Then you have all the data necessary to continue.

This implementation means that all the data you need is contained within the packet that you have received, and you don't have to check where it came from. The extra few bytes of data won't slow you down as much as having to perform a search every time you receive a packet.

**Edit In response to OP Edit**

Alternatively, instead of implementing an Array, you can implement a `HashMap<String,Player>`. That way, all you need to do is grab the username from the packet sent, using my description above, and pass it to the hashmap. The hashmap can return the User object that represents the client, and there is no need, again, for an index lookup.

You can find the documentation on the [Java Hashmap here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Finally, I noticed you've got a `player` class. The Java convention is that all classes start with an upper case letter. That is:

`player` should be `Player`.

**Final edit in response to your comment**

Your problem is an issue of bad design, I'm afraid. The clients should all be communicating to the server via the same channel, in this context. That way all the server has to do is listen out for any messages, parse them, and move them on. Adjust your implementation so that your client's all talk to the server via the same stream, and that will eliminate your issue.

Comment: Or else make use of XML rather than comma separated strings. XStream is a great library: http://xstream.codehaus.org/

Comment: Yes, XML is always an excellent Option. I just figured, if OP hasn't quite established communication we could start of simpler, then move onto more complicated, industry standard methods of communication.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and ur answers but thats not the problem i have.

From Server to Client I just do player[i].out.writeUTF(message) and Client then just checks his "in", doing in.readUTF() and all works fine.

From Client to Server i do out.writeUTF(message) from Client but then, on the Server side i have to choose one player[i].in to read which i dont know which player is.

Comment: @auron344 Although its bad design, one quick fix is that you  send the ith value (i) to the client and send it back to the server once it sends information.

Comment: @Chris Cooney  How can i do that? Every time a player logs into the Server i generate an input and output stream for him and put him in the array. I dont know how to implement the clients communicate with the server the same channel, really.

Comment: When the Server is created, create ONE input channel for the server. Each time a player logs in, generate their unique input stream, and pass them your ONE input channel. The Client will then communicate to you via the same input channel. From there, with each message, the client passes their unique identifier. You use that unique identifier with the HashMap to get their Unique stream, and you write the relevant data to it.

Comment: A pleasure. Given my answer is the most helpful, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Sorry i'm new here and it doesnt let me to vote answers (requires 15 reputation)...

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can mark answers as correct, but it's not important. It's just that this question has been answered, so we want to get it off the unanswered list. :)

Comment: Oh yes! I didnt see the option, sorry!

I putted it as correct. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: 'your ONE input channel' and 'the same stream' are meaningless. There are only sockets, and they are different per client, and so are their streams.

Comment: I was attempting to use the same terminology that OP used, to aid their understanding. It doesn't mean much to you, because it isn't the correct terminology. But each Client communicates to the Server via the same ServerSocket, which is bound to the same port.

Answer (score 2):

Ok first let me give you a small background on how sockets work, before giving you the solution and it is vital to understand what is going on.

**Socket Explanation** ([Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html))

A socket is a software endpoint that establishes **bidirectional** communication between a server program and one or more client programs. Note the word bidirectional. This means that for **each** connection between a client and a server, you have two streams: an input stream and an output stream. These can be accessed by both socket objects that one sets up on the server side and client side.

[image]

**Your Problem**

> From Server to Client I just do player[i].out.writeUTF(message) and
>   Client then just checks his "in", doing in.readUTF() and all works
>   fine. From Client to Server i do out.writeUTF(message) from Client but
>   then, on the Server side i have to choose one player[i].in to read
>   which i dont know which player is.

Therefore, if I understood correctly, you have a difficulty in how to determine which client sent you a message. This is easy to solve if you use multithreading correctly, as each client will be handled on a separate thread.

A vital step is how clients are handled initially. Consider the following code. In order to keep it short, I did not focus greatly on conventions.

```
ArrayList<ClientWorker> clientWorkers = new ArrayList<ClientWorker>();
int idCounter = 0;

    public void listenSocket(){
      try{
        int port = 9090
        server = new ServerSocket();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
      }
      while(true){
        ClientWorker w;
        try{
    //server.accept returns a client connection
          clientWorker = new ClientWorker(server.accept(), idCounter, );
          idCounter++;
          clientWorkers.add(clientWorker); 
          Thread t = new Thread(clientWorker);
          t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.exit(-1);
        }
      }
    }
```

Ok so through that code, we are handling new clients and assigning them with a unique key. Instead of array, I am using arraylists so that it can increase and descrease in size according to the number of users connected to the server. Once a client is received, I create a clientWorker instance. Furthermore, a unique key is assigned for each connected user, which can be used to fetch its object from the arraylist (if required).

The ClientWorker class looks something like this:

```
    class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
      private Socket client;
      public int id

    //Constructor
      ClientWorker(Socket client, int id) {
        this.client = client;
        this.id = id;
      }

      public void run(){
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try{
          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
          out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("in or out failed");
          System.exit(-1);
        }

        while(true){
          try{
//ANY DATA I GET FROM THIS STREAM IS FROM THIS PARTICULAR CLIENT ONLY!
            line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("RECEIVED FROM CLIENT "+ id +" " + line);
           }catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
           }
        }
      }
    }
```

This thread calls the run() method. Since each client has a separate thread, the data handled from a particular thread is sent from that particular client and not someone else. Therefore, one can distinguish each client's data easily.

Sorry its a long answer. It took sometime so that I reach my point.

[References](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

Comment: THAT is exactly what i have done after @Chris Cooney answered saying it was bad implemented. I watched a video [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1ThWf9Fkfo explaining exactly the same as you do. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for an absolutely excellent answer. Really complements the question! :)

Comment: @auron344 Glad to be of help :)